# JS array, don't push if var = 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I'm trying to make a script for the game "Ogame", and I'm looking for some help about javascript array which is not my thing, I admit it.

```
// Civil ships
    var TransporterSmall = 0; // Petit Transporteur
    var TransporterLarge = 1500; // Grand Transporteur
    var ColonyShip = 0; // Vaisseau de Colonisation
    var Recycler = 0; // Recycleur
    var Probe = 1; // Sonde

// Battle ships
    var FighterLight = 0; // Chasseur Léger
    var FighterHeavy = 0; // Chasseur Lourd
    var Cruiser = 0; // Croiseur
    var Battleship = 0; // Vaisseau de Bataille
    var Interceptor = 0; // Traqueur
    var Bomber = 0; // Bombardier
    var Destroyer = 1; // Destructeur
    var Deathstar = 0; // EDLM
    var Reaper = 1; // Faucheur
    var Explorer = 1; // Eclaireur
```

Here is the code where the player set manually a number for each ship.

Then he has a button, when he clicks on it, it pushes in an array. But I would like that if the var = 0, it's not pushed (really important)

```
document.getElementById('AutoSelect').onclick = function() {
        fleetDispatcher.shipsToSend = []; // Empty array
        fleetDispatcher.shipsToSend.push(
            {id:202,number: TransporterSmall},
            {id:203,number: TransporterLarge},
            {id:208,number: ColonyShip},
            {id:209,number: Recycler},
            {id:210,number: Probe},
            {id:204,number: FighterLight},
            {id:205,number: FighterHeavy},
            {id:206,number: Cruiser},
            {id:207,number: Battleship},
            {id:215,number: Interceptor},
            {id:211,number: Bomber},
            {id:213,number: Destroyer},
            {id:214,number: Deathstar},
            {id:218,number: Reaper},
            {id:219,number: Explorer});
        fleetDispatcher.refresh();
    };
```

I don't know how to proceed honestly, it's all confuse in my brain. Hope you can help me, thanks !

Comment: You've to store the ships in an array (or an object) instead of the variables from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can using array filtering and the spread operator to accomplish this:

```
document.getElementById('AutoSelect').onclick = function() {
        fleetDispatcher.shipsToSend = []; // Empty array
        fleetDispatcher.shipsToSend.push(...([
            {id:202,number: TransporterSmall},
            {id:203,number: TransporterLarge},
            {id:208,number: ColonyShip},
            {id:209,number: Recycler},
            {id:210,number: Probe},
            {id:204,number: FighterLight},
            {id:205,number: FighterHeavy},
            {id:206,number: Cruiser},
            {id:207,number: Battleship},
            {id:215,number: Interceptor},
            {id:211,number: Bomber},
            {id:213,number: Destroyer},
            {id:214,number: Deathstar},
            {id:218,number: Reaper},
            {id:219,number: Explorer}]
          .filter(item -> item.number !== 0))
        );
        fleetDispatcher.refresh();
    };
```

(I haven't thoroughly checked the syntax of the above, but that's at least roughly what I'm getting at.)

The basic idea is:

1. Take that long list of items and turn them into an array by wrapping them in square brackets.
2. Use `filter` to weed out all of the array items where `number` is 0.
3. Use the spread operator (`...`) to turn the array back into a list of arguments for `push`, but now with the zero-count items gone.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code, I never used the array filter, and I didn't even know there was a spread operator. I'm reading some informations about it at the same time to understand ^^'

Comment: You could also skip the spread operator, use the code as you originally wrote it, and clean up the zero-count items after-the-fact, like this: `fleetDispatcher.shipsToSend = fleetDispatcher.shipsToSend.filter(item -> item.number !== 0)`

Comment: Thanks for help, filter helped me ! :)

Comment: Please just remember to select this as your chosen answer, and upvote it too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a ternary condition.

If TransporterSmall is superior to zero, then the second part is an object so it is pushed. If not superior to zero, then null (nothing is pushed) :

```
document.getElementById('AutoSelect').onclick = function() {
        fleetDispatcher.shipsToSend = []; // Empty array
        fleetDispatcher.shipsToSend.push(

            TransporterSmall > 0 ? {id:202,number: TransporterSmall} : null,
            etc...

        fleetDispatcher.refresh();
    };
```

Comment: This won't work, at least not as you describe. `null` is not ignored by `push`, it adds a `null` item to the array.

Comment: Just try this in your browser console: `a = [1, 2, 3].push(null)`. You'll find that the value of `a` is `[1, 2, 3, null]`.

Comment: Yep, doesn't work, nothing happens when I click on the button

Comment: So i guess that using && operator will do the job, instead of ternary :
TransporterSmall > 0 && {id:202,number: TransporterSmall}

Comment: That would just push extra `0` values into the array instead of nulls. There isn't any argument that `push` skips over without adding a item to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Finally succeeded. Filter was the key. Thanks for help !

```
document.getElementById('AutoSelect').onclick = function() {

        let ships = [
            {id:202,number: TransporterSmall},
            {id:203,number: TransporterLarge},
            {id:208,number: ColonyShip},
            {id:209,number: Recycler},
            {id:210,number: Probe},
            {id:204,number: FighterLight},
            {id:205,number: FighterHeavy},
            {id:206,number: Cruiser},
            {id:207,number: Battleship},
            {id:215,number: Interceptor},
            {id:211,number: Bomber},
            {id:213,number: Destroyer},
            {id:214,number: Deathstar},
            {id:218,number: Reaper},
            {id:219,number: Explorer}
        ];

        fleetDispatcher.shipsToSend = []; // Empty array
        fleetDispatcher.shipsToSend = ships.filter(id => id.number > 0);
        fleetDispatcher.refresh();
    };
```